# How do I extract the extrapolation prediction when setting the gamma argument in the specaccum function?

Tags: biostatistics, ecology, vegan, extrapolation

I am trying to use the `specaccum` function from the R `vegan` package to develop species accumulation curves.

However, I am trying to set the `gamma` argument to return the extrapolated number of species, but I do not know how to extract the results. Do I have to use `specpool` function separately?
Here is what I am attempting:

```
library(vegan)
data(BCI)
specaccum(comm = BCI, method = "random", gamma = "chao")
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is not very clear, but it does indicate that `gamma` is only used with `method = "exact"` *and* `conditioned = FALSE`, and then it only influences the estimated SD of the accumulation curve. I'll improve the documentation.

If you want to get an estimate of extrapolated species richness, you should use specific tools for that, such as `vegan::specpool` (and there are other packages). However, `vegan::specaccum` cannot extrapolate accumulation *curves* – only their estimated SD.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the help!